# Best way to debug javascript while there is no error message for reading non-existing field from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

```
const ball = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2,
    size: 10,
    speed: 4,
    dx: 4,
    dy: -4
}

// draw ball on canvas 
function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.xize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0095dd';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

I'm trying to draw a ball using canvas.

```
ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.xize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
```

This line calls arc() and tries to read `ball.size` by access `ball.xize`. It's a typo.
In languages I'm familiar with, typos like this result in error messages that can help quickly identify the cause. There is none with javascript. What is the canonical way to debug javascript in such cases? Do we have to read and verify each and every line like what I did here?

Comment: Use TypeScript or at least a type-aware linter. I consider TypeScript essential for working on any semi-professional script that isn't trivial. It has a learning curve, but it's well worth it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImtKd.png

Comment: `console.log(...)` :)

Comment: @steve_pineapple I would argue that the console log is a terrible debugging tool. Live updating objects and incorrect interpretation of stringified values account for a very large percentage of [tag:javascript] questions on StackOverflow